# SOLR: Find a SOLR hit within a document

Tags: solr

Is there anyway to find the location (perhaps the page or byte/character offset) within a document where each of the search hits returned occurred? The purpose is to move to that location in a viewer when the user selects it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: each term also stores the offsets into the document. So when a match comes back, Lucene at least has this information in the index unless you explicitly omit it in your schema

Comment: Thanks. The "official" info appears to be here- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent